# Error MSB4062 when trying to use ServiceController

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I use Visual Studio 2010 with TFS 2010 on a x64 machine.

I am trying to use the MSBuild Community Tasks target in my build. This target exists in source control. So in my csproj file i am import that particular target but i now get the following error:

error MSB4062: The "MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSB
uild.Community.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Program F
iles (x86)\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll' or one of
 its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
 declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies
are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Micros
oft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\SampleTest\SampleTest.csproj]

Here is my code:

```
   <Import Project="..\..\Builds\Common\MSBuildTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
   <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyService>ServiceName</MyService>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ServiceController ServiceName="$(MyService)" Action="Stop" />-->
  </Target>
```

Any thoughts on the above?

Why is MSBuild trying to look for the dll elsewhere when i have specified it in the project file?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem comes from within the [MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Source/MSBuild.Community.Tasks/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets) file - it is this file that actually references the `MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll` assembly.

If you open the file you can see a bunch of `UsingTask` elements, such as:

```xml
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)" TaskName="MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Attrib" />
```

The `$(MSBuildCommunityTasksLib)` property is defined at the top of the file as:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksPath Condition="'$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks</MSBuildCommunityTasksPath>
    <MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.dll</MSBuildCommunityTasksLib>
</PropertyGroup>
```

So it looks like you need to set the `$(MSBuildCommunityTasksPath)` property before calling `<Import>`.